# Не удается подключить css-файл от Bootstrap

Tags: python, django, bootstrap

Пытаюсь подключить css-файл следующим образом:

```
{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
```

Однако, браузер выдает следующую ошибку:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Файл находится по директории:

mySite\mainApp\static\css\bootstrap.css

Некоторые настройки файла setting.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'mainApp',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Проблема на проде или с dev-сервером?

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, dev-сервер

Comment: Тогда показываете INSTALLED_APPS, STATICFILES_FINDERS, если определён и urlpatterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

или положить файлы в `mySite/static/` если одно приложение то все равно. Если их несколько будет путаница.

В идеале сделай путь `mySite\mainApp\static\mainApp\css\bootstrap.css`. 
Будет удобнее когда сделаешь `collectstatic` и все соберется в одну папку.

Comment: У меня идет подключение к bootstrap, поэтому css не должны конфликтовать, но всё равно спасибо :)